# How can you make a snowflake shape rotate to its center, with canvas and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a script that emulates snowing using a snowflake shape that rotates in its center as it falls.

The problem is that trying ctx.rotate(), rotates all the snowflakes in the center of the canvas and not to each individual flake to its center.
The code.

```
    (function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();
    var flakes = [],
        c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
        flakeCount = 100
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    init();

    function init() {
        for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
                y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
                speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5
            img = draw();
            flakes.push({
                img: img,
                velY: speed,
                velX: 0,
                x: x,
                y: y,
                color: getRandomColor()
            });
        }
        snow();
    }
    function snow() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
            var flake = flakes[i]
            flake.y += flake.velY;
            flake.x += flake.velX+getRand(0.1,0.3);
            if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
                reset(flake);
            }
            if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
                reset(flake);
            }
            ctx.filter = flake.color;
            ctx.drawImage(flake.img, flake.x, flake.y)
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(snow);
    };
    function reset(flake) {
        flake.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        flake.y = 0;
        flake.speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
        flake.velY = flake.speed;
        flake.velX = 0;
        flake.color = getRandomColor()
    }
    function draw() {
        let c = document.createElement('canvas');
        var canvas = c;
        c.width = window.innerWidth;
        c.height = window.innerHeight;
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var width = canvas.width;
            var height = canvas.height;
            context.lineWidth = 20;
            context.lineCap = 'round';
            context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)";
            context.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
            context.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
            context.scale(0.1, 0.1)
            context.translate(width/2,height/2);
            for(var count = 0; count < 6; count++) {
                context.save();     
                drawSegment(context, 100, 40);
                drawSegment(context, 100, 80);
                drawSegment(context, 100, 0);
                context.restore();          
                context.rotate(Math.PI/3);
            }
        }
        return canvas;
    }
    function drawSegment(context, segmentLength, branchLength) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(segmentLength,0);
        context.stroke();
        context.translate(segmentLength,0);
        if (branchLength > 0) {
            drawBranch(context, branchLength, 1);
            drawBranch(context, branchLength, -1);
        }
    }
    function drawBranch(context, branchLength, direction) {
        context.save();
        context.rotate(direction*Math.PI/3);
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(branchLength,0);
        context.stroke();
        context.restore();
    }
```

In the following JSFiddle you can find the code
https://jsfiddle.net/hkz3nyfL/7/

(You will notice that the shape appears broken on the top side, i dont know why it does that, it happens because the screen is too small)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that on each animation frame you want each snowflake to rotate about tis own center? And if so by how much, a random amount or constant for each snowflake or the same across all snowflakes?

Comment: Hello, yes i want it to rotate about its own center. On the second question, it doesn't matter how, but the ideal is (eg. for each snowflake rotate 30degrees right, then return to 0, then rotate 30degrees left, return to 0 etc)

Comment: How much time for a snowflake  to rotate the 30 degrees? Or is it random between two bounds or....?

Comment: The time can be random as long as the animation is smooth.

Comment: Before doing the canvas rotation you'll have to translate it so the center of the snowflake is in the center of the canvas, then translate it back.

Comment: Incidentally, there is already quite a bit of work going on and my browser, on a fairly powerful laptop, is saying the requestAnimationFrames are taking too long. You may be better off converting each snowflake canvas to an img and using image rotation in the hopes the GPU gets used to speed things up, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Of course! The idea is that i create the shape, transformations in an image are acceptable!

Answer (score 1):

Running the given code my browser (Edge) complained occasionally about a violation - it seemed too much JS runtime was required between requestAnimationFrames - which I think means that it couldn't keep up with the normal 60fps.

The GPU usage ranged between 98 and 100%. The problem is that just too much work is being done on 100 canvases, drawing them onto the master canvas for each frame.

Moving to using img elements instead of canvases for each snowflake, but still drawing them using the canvas technique given in the question, and animating each using CSS animations, no violations were flagged and the GPU usage was around 30%.

Note: there was also a problem that the given code did not run properly on Safari. This was due to the use of canvas filter so redrawing the img with its new color after each animation cycle was substituted.

Now to get round to answering the question!

Pursuing the canvas rotation route is off because of the high processing usage so sticking with the img route, each snowflake can be rotated by adding rotate(30deg) etc to the keyframes. The GPU usage goes up, to somewhere between 40 and 50%, but there are no violations flagged. As an aside, the GPU usage was consistently higher on Firefox than on Edge on a Windows 10 laptop.

Here is a snippet using imgs instead of canvases. There is some tidying up needed on initial condition, and we note that the snowflakes are a fixed size. For a responsive solution they probably should be sized proportional to the viewport minimum dimension. Each snowflake has a fixed number of rotates and if this is required to change it would be better to calculate the keyframes in the JS for a more general solution.

```js
function loaded() {
    const flakeCount = 100;
    const flakesEl = document.getElementById('flakes');
    
    const imgc = document.getElementById('canvas'); // work space on which to draw a snowflake of random color
    
    // FF seemed to require that this is done rather than just innerWidth which was smaller than 100vw 
    const width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    const height= Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    
    init();
    function init() {
        for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
            let flakeEl = document.createElement('img');
            flakeEl.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', animationEnd);
            flakeEl.addEventListener('animationend', animationEnd);
            flakeEl.style.animationDuration = ((Math.random() * 1) + 0.5) * 10 + 's';
            flakeEl.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + 'px';
            flakeEl.style.top = '-100px';
            flakeEl.classList.add('descend');
            flakeEl.classList.remove('descend1');
            draw(flakeEl);
            flakesEl.appendChild(flakeEl);
        }
    }    
    function animationEnd(event) {
      reset(event.target);
    }
    function reset(flakeEl) {
        flakeEl.style.top = '-100px';
        flakeEl.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + 'px';
        flakeEl.style.animationDuration = ((Math.random() * 1) + 0.5) * 10 + 's';
        flakeEl.style.animationDelay = '0s';
        draw(flakeEl);
        flakeEl.classList.toggle('descend');
        flakeEl.classList.toggle('descend1');
    }
    function getRandomColor() {
        let color = `invert(${getRand(40,50)}%) sepia(${getRand(30,100)}%) hue-rotate(${getRand(-360,360)}deg) saturate(${getRand(10,50)})`;
        // Safari does not support canvas fill filter so we just use a normal rgb for this test
        return 'rgb('+getRand(0, 255)+', '+getRand(0, 255)+', '+getRand(0, 255)+')';
    }
    function getRand(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    function draw(flakeEl) {
        imgc.width = 650; // enough spaace to get a whole snowflake in
        imgc.height = imgc.width;
            var imgctx = imgc.getContext('2d');
            var width = imgc.width;
            var height = imgc.height;
            imgctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            imgctx.lineWidth = 20;
            imgctx.lineCap = 'round';
            imgctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)";
            imgctx.strokeStyle = getRandomColor();
            imgctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            imgctx.translate(width/2,height/2);
            for(var count = 0; count < 6; count++) {
                imgctx.save();      
                drawSegment(imgctx, 100, 40);
                drawSegment(imgctx, 100, 80);
                drawSegment(imgctx, 100, 0);
                imgctx.restore();           
                imgctx.rotate(Math.PI/3);
            }
        flakeEl.src = imgc.toDataURL();
    }
    function drawSegment(context, segmentLength, branchLength) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(segmentLength,0);
        context.stroke();
        context.translate(segmentLength,0);
        if (branchLength > 0) {
            drawBranch(context, branchLength, 1);
            drawBranch(context, branchLength, -1);
        }
    }
    function drawBranch(context, branchLength, direction) {
        context.save();
        context.rotate(direction*Math.PI/3);
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(branchLength,0);
        context.stroke();
        context.restore();
    }
}
window.onload = loaded;
```

```css
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  roverflow: hidden;
}
#flakes {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: descend1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.descend {
  animation-name: descend;
}

.descend1 {
  animation-name: descend1;
  }

@keyframes descend {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  16.66% {
    transform: translateY(calc(16.66vh + 16.66px)) rotate(30deg);
  }
  33.32% {
    transform: translateY(calc(33.32vh + 33.32px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  49.98% {
    transform: translateY(calc(49.98vh + 49.98px)) rotate(-30deg);
  }
  66.64% {
    transform: translateY(calc(66.64vh + 66.64px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  83.30% {
    transform: translateY(calc(83.30vh + 83.30px)) rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vh + 100px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes descend1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  16.66% {
    transform: translateY(calc(16.66vh + 16.66px)) rotate(30deg);
  }
  33.32% {
    transform: translateY(calc(33.32vh + 33.32px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  49.98% {
    transform: translateY(calc(49.98vh + 49.98px)) rotate(-30deg);
  }
  66.64% {
    transform: translateY(calc(66.64vh + 66.64px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
  83.30% {
    transform: translateY(calc(83.30vh + 83.30px)) rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vh + 100px)) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="flakes"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. But it is not made exclusively with canvas and JS.

Comment: That’s why I asked if it was ok to go to imgs, which I thought you’d said was acceptable. Sorry I misunderstood. You can’t do it entirely with canvas, it takes far too much processor time and so skips frames, even before introducing rotations, and you’ll end up with jerky animations.

Comment: Yes, i know it is difficult. Canvas to image is acceptable, animation with CSS isn't. Animation should be only with JS and canvas. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, understood. I don’t think you can do it and not lose frames. I’ve had a similar situation before and just could not make the rendering on canvas quick enough, but good luck